# On product page,set some attribute's value pre selected

Tags: product, product-attribute

I have two attributes of product.When product page is loaded that time I want to preselect value on page.

Please check below image:

[image]

All products are of "**Simple Product Type**"

So is it possible ? How ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You create Dropdown attribute for days, right?